# Loading variable image sizes in Android from service

Tags: android, image, service

In my application, I would like to show full device-width (portrait) banner images that are 16:9. I'm using Picasso to download/display the images from a url provided by a backend service that I own.

My question is: **what are some strategies that people are using to do this type of thing?**

Note: I have searched around for ideas and haven't found much specific help.

Some approaches that come to mind:

**Approach A:** Have the service vend the high-res image, and resize it with Picasso. 
**Pros**: simple, don't need logic for which photo to grab.
**Cons**: small devices will need to use bandwidth & storage space to download images at resolutions they won't be able to display.

**Approach B:**
Have 5 different versions of the image on the service (mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi, & xxxhdpi) and grab each of these depending on the device I'm calling from, like so:

```
File ext            Dimensions
------------------------------
_mdpi.jpg           360x203
_hdpi.jpg           540x304
_xhdpi.jpg          720x405
_xxhdpi.jpg         1080x608
_xxxhdpi.jpg        1440x810
```

This looks like it would work alright for phones, but once I throw tablets into the mix things get a bit more messy. Following this further, I could use a smallest width qualifier, as Android does, and vend even more images from the service. So something along the lines of...

```
File ext            Dimensions
------------------------------
_mdpi.jpg           360x203
_hdpi.jpg           540x304
_xhdpi.jpg          720x405
_xxhdpi.jpg         1080x608
_xxxhdpi.jpg        1440x810
_sw600-mdpi.jpg     600x338
_sw600-hdpi.jpg     800x450
_sw600-xhdpi.jpg    1200x675
...
_sw720-mdpi.jpg     720x405
_sw720-hdpi.jpg     1080x608
_sw720-xhdpi.jpg    1440x810
...
```

But this doesn't handle even larger devices (e.g. Pixel C) that have a width of 900dp (as the 'sw720-xhdpi' 1440x810 image would need to be upscaled to 1800x1013).

**Pros:** I'm downloading very close to the right size for each device to display. **Cons:** seems overly complex as for every single Image I now need to add many different copies of it and have device code that can figure out what type of device I'm on and get the proper image from the service.

**Approach C:** your approach here.

I'm possibly looking for an in-between, or if you have done something completely different, I'm open to hearing about that as well.

Comment: Why not store only the highest res image server side and use your server-side logic to resize and serve up the desired resolution based on a screen-size parameter?

Comment: Definitely an option I hadn't considered. Right now, the server sends back a url of the image, which is nice to then hand off to a library to download/cache/display. Are you suggesting, with this approach, that we would instead serve the actual image in a service call? I like this idea for the ease of app decision code, but if I instead now have to cache and download on my own, I'm not sure if it will be worth it.

Comment: Caching and downloading with a LRUCache is really not very difficult, although a more persistent cache would be a bit more complicated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case it helps anyone in the future, I ended up doing a form of option B that uses 3 different bucket sizes to serve images. The buckets are based on screen width, as follows: S: 0-599px, M: 600-1199px, L: 1200+px.

Not necessarily the most elegant, but has been working fairly well thus far.